# lightning__commerce_cartChanged channel is not updating the amount of cart items in the LWR site

Tags: lightning-web-components, b2b-commerce, lwr, lightning-message-channel

I'm currently in progress with migrating from Aura B2B Store to LWR Site, custom components for adding products to cart publish messages to lightning__commerce_cartChanged channel as described here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389948&type=1 and it works as expeted in Aura template but doesn't work in LWR store.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import {
 publish,
 MessageContext
} from "lightning/messageService";

import cartChanged from "@salesforce/messageChannel/lightning__commerce_cartChanged";
export default class CartUpdatingComponent extends LightningElement {
 @wire(MessageContext)
 messageContext;


 /**
  * Handles a user button click to add a product to their cart.
  */
 addToCart(event) {
   addToCartAsync(...)
      .then(() => {
        publish(this.messageContext, cartChanged);
      });
 }
}
```

Is it possible to make this functionality work inside LWR store?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that if you import the newly accessible api:

```
import { addItemToCart } from 'commerce/cartApi';
```

and use it like below, the event will automatically refresh your cart widget.

```
addItemToCart(productId, quantity)
  .then(() => {
    this.showProductAddedToCartToast();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.showError(error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.isProcessing = false;
  });
```

Link to the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_b2c_comm_dev.meta/b2b_b2c_comm_dev/b2b_b2c_comm_display_lwc_apis.htm

I think the event is still needed and should be fixed but maybe this helps as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- import { refreshCartSummary } from 'commerce/cartApi';

If you do the processing of the products and add them to the cart, for example, in Apex.

- import { addItemToCart } from 'commerce/cartApi'; or import { addItemsToCart } from 'commerce/cartApi';

Comment: I can't find any examples anywhere of actually how to use the "addItemToCart" imported function. Any chance you have a link to a working example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

One hint, while it is not clearly described in Salesforce documentation. Commerce/cartApi method addItemsToCart parameter has a such structure:
`{"productId_1": quantity_1,"productId_2":quantity_2}` and so on.